# Qt Installer Framework: How to check if component is selected for installation

Tags: qt, qt-installer

Concerning the Qt Installer Framework I have this question:

How can I check in a component script if this component is currently selected for installation in the Component Selection Page?

There is no component property for that and I can not find a value that can be queried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the functions

```
component.componentChangeRequested();
component.installationRequested();
component.updateRequested();
component.uninstallationRequested();
```

to query information about requested component changes.

All of these functions depend on the previous state of the package. Checked packages that are uninstalled will be marked in `installationRequested`, unchecked packages that are installed will be marked in `uninstallationRequested`, and checked packages whose installed version is older than the bundled version will be marked in `updateRequested`.

For further information check the [component Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-component.html).

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `installer` object can return the list of all components.
See: https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#components-method

A "component" object has an `installed` attribute in addition the methods cited by here by Moose.
See: https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-component.html

Here's some helpful QtScript to cut, paste, and perhaps modify for your use case:

```
function getComponent( name ) {
    var comps=installer.components();
    for( i=0; i< comps.length; i++ ) {
        if( comps[i].name == name ) return comps[i];
    }
    throw new Error( "Component not found: " + name );
}

function isComponentInstalled( name ) {
    try{ return getComponent( name ).installed; }
    catch(e){ console.log( "Component not found: " + name ); }
    return false;
}

function isComponentSelected( name ) {
    try{ return getComponent( name ).installationRequested(); }
    catch(e){ console.log( "Component not found: " + name ); }
    return false;
}
```